# Magento 2 - can't access admin (backend) after setting up custom Admin URL

Tags: magento2, admin, backend

I changed the custom admin URL via the admin.

I've set **Stores -> Settings: Configuration -> Advanced: Admin -> Admin Base URL -> Use Custom Admin URL** to **Yes**

I've set **Stores -> Settings: Configuration -> Advanced: Admin -> Custom Admin URL -> Custom Admin URL** to **adminxyz**

but just after saving it showed me the 404 site.

[image]

Now I can't access the admin (backend) anymore:

So I opened phpMyAdmin and noticed that in the table `core_config_data` the entries with path **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** changed to **adminxyz**.

So I changed them back to my domain **https://www.example.com/**

I also set the of path **admin/url/use_custom** from **1** to **0**.

But I still can't login in the backend.

I already flushed the cache and reindexed.

If I execute `php bin/magento info:adminuri` then I get:

```
Admin URI: /adminxyz
```

I even made this entry in my **app/etc/env.php**:

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'adminxyz'
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all files inside **var/cache**, now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

use command line interface to set admin URL instead of manually setting it.

bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="backend_front_name"

Answer (score 0):

query Database:
**select * from core_config_data where path = 'admin/url/custom';**

and change path = {your domain}

- bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="{optional}"
  **admin, admin_test,... **
- bin/magento se:up
- bin/magento s:s:d -f
- bin/magento c:f